# What is a good general guideline for mixed effects model building?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, modeling

Suppose I have a dependent variable and half a dozen possible predictors. This experiment is wholly exploratory.

What would be the best approach to discover which predictors (and interactions between them) best predict the data?

By this I mean, what general guideline do I use when comparing models? Which fixed effects do I add and in what order? When do I add random effects?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of your dataset, but you could either use some form of variable selection procedure using AIC or BIC. If you have a large enough dataset you could also use k-fold cross validation to select the best predictive model. see also this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773620/could-we-do-backward-elimination-with-mixed-model-using-lmer) on stack overflow. Regarding the Random effects, you would usually add it from the beginning and this depends on the design of the data under consideration.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! If I did use AIC would I use a fully automated approach? If not, how would I know what order to add predictors? Also in terms of the random effects, I'm not sure how I would add them in the beginning if some fixed effects that might end up having random slopes aren't in there yet?

Thanks again!

Comment: Ideally you would use a fully automated approach and ultimately, it will depend on the number of predictors you have,. As you might have seen from the link above, automation will depend on which package you plan to employ. If the number of predictors are small say 3-4 you could probably run all combinations of models. One point about the random effects is that you need to make sure your mixed model package employs ML and not some sort of pseudo likelihood approach for model fitting. Else models with different random effects are not comparable.

Comment: Also, in general a stepwise or backward elimination procedure should obviate the need for the order of entry of variables into the model. Make sure you also check for collinearity among your predictors first

Comment: Thanks! I am getting a bunch of significant predictors that don't make too much sense so I'm a bit wary. But I will cut down on the number of predictors I am starting with.

In terms of collinearity, would I compute a correlation matrix keeping the data at the trial level (the level that it's being analyzed at in the model) or collapse across subjects/items first?

Thanks again!

Comment: In my opinion, I would just use all as these are the independent variables. You should get the same answer both ways

Comment: Thanks!

Any advice on following up an interaction between a categorical and continuous variable? I haven't found consistent advice online. Would I run the model exactly the same way, except splitting on the categorical variable and see how that affects the results of the continuous variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38668/discussion-between-dave-and-ashokrags).